# Проверка переполнения определенных битов

Tags: c++, c

Складываю числа, например

> 0xAABB + 0xAABB (10101010_10111011 + 10101010_10111011 = **1**_0101010**1**_01110110)

Как мне посмотреть произошло ли переполнение выделенных бит. Особенно остро стоит вопрос с переполнением, возникающим при сложении первого байта числа (0xBB).

> Сдвиги НЕ применять. IF'ы использовать НЕЛЬЗЯ. MMX, SSE и т.д. тоже
>   НЕТ.

Comment: if ( ((0xAABB & 0xFF) + (0xAABB & 0xFF)) > 0xFF) - было переполнение в младшем байте. Примерно аналогично можно написать и для старшего.

Comment: if ы тоже нельзя использовать, забыл указать

Comment: тогда либо ассемблерные вставки, либо расширения компилятора - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins (это для gcc).

Comment: чувак, задавший мне эту задачку, говорит что он использовал лишь арифметику. А ассемблерные вставки это не simd инструкции?

Comment: @neko69 так не используйте if: bool res = (((0xAABB & 0xFF) + (0xAABB & 0xFF)) > 0xFF) - никаких сдвигов и if'ов.

Comment: тогда придется складывать побайтово - тоже нет. побайтово я реализовал, но требуется так, чтобы сложение происходило сразу. (да, я знаю, требования дичь полная)

Comment: @neko69, откуда у Вас регулярно возникают столь непрактичные задачки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для беззнакового сложения все просто - при беззнаковом сложении переполнение возникает, если полученная сумма меньше (при беззнаковом сравнении) любого из операндов. (Уоррен, Алгоритмические трюки)

Так что просто смотрите на получившийся байт (и два байта) и сравнивайте. Что-то вроде

```
unsigned short int sum(unsigned short int a, unsigned short int b)
{
    unsigned short int s = a + b;
    if ((s&0xFF < a&0xFF) && (s&0xFF < b&0xFF))
        cout << "Переполнение 8 бита" << endl;
    if ((s < a) && (s < b))
        cout << "Переполнение 16 бита" << endl;
    return s;
}
```

Без if'ов - Уроррен дает такие варианты, как (с - перенос, т.е. рассматривается сумма x+y+c):

```
(x&y)|((x|y)&~(x+y+c))
(x>>1)+(y>>1)+(((x&y)|((x|y)&c))&1)
```

Ну, в вашем случае c==0, что упрощает дело... Усложняет то, что проверку надо считать отдельно от суммирования, и отдельно для байтов и слов.

Update:

```
unsigned short int sum(unsigned short int x, unsigned short int y,
                       bool&carry8, bool& carry16)
{
    unsigned short int s = x+y;
    carry16 = ((x&y)|((x|y)&~s));
    carry8  = carry16&0x80;
    carry16 = carry16&0x8000;
    return s;
}
```

Исчерпывающий перебор подтверждает правильность. Сдвигов нет, if'ов нет.

Устраивает?

Comment: а как это сделать без if'ов и проверок каждого байта отдельно?

Comment: @neko69 А, да, каюсь, был невнимателен, не обратил внимания на запрет if. Сейчас покопаюсь... Подправил ответ.

Comment: Сдвиги тоже нельзя

Comment: @neko69 Вот, обновил ответ, привел код, проверил - работает. Такое устроит?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    auto first = 0xAABB;
    auto second = 0xAABB;
    auto leastByteSum = (first & 0xFF) + (second & 0xFF);
    bool leastByteOverflow = (leastByteSum & 0xFF) != leastByteSum;
    auto mostByteSum = (first & 0xFF00) + (second & 0xFF00);
    bool mostByteOverflow = (mostByteSum & 0xFFFF) != mostByteSum;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Did least byte overflow: " << leastByteOverflow << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Did most byte overflow: " << mostByteOverflow << "\n";
}
```

Или вот так:

```
auto first = 0xAABB;
auto second = 0xAABB;
auto ninthBit = 0b1'0000'0000;
bool leastByteOverflow = ((first ^ second) & ninthBit) != ((first + second) & ninthBit);
bool mostByteOverflow = ((first + second) & 0xFFFF) != (first + second);
```

А ещё вот такая вариация предыдущего решения:

```
auto first = 0xAABB;
auto second = 0xAABB;
auto ninthBit = 0b1'0000'0000;
bool leastByteOverflow = (first ^ second) ^ (first + second) & ninthBit;
bool mostByteOverflow = ((first + second) & 0x10000) > 0;
```